# Transform Second Difference Predictions from VAR model back to levels

Tags: r, time-series, data-transformation, vector-autoregression, differences

I am currently working with a VAR model in R using the second difference of some variables (it only becomes stationary after differencing twice). So far I'm trying to see if the model fits one of the variables which seems to be the case to a reasonable amount. However, when I'm trying to transform the fitted values back to levels they look terrible (basically a straight downtrend). I managed to transform the differenced y values used by the model back to their level scale without problems. I'm now trying to assess if the model simply fails to fit or if I missed something. Below I included the code I've used:

```
model <- VAR(df_diff2[3:nrow(df_diff2),], p = 1, type = "none", ic = "SC")
fit <- model$varresult$Variable_of_interest$fitted.values
fit_levels <- diffinv(x = fit, differences = 2, xi = df_raw[c(1,2),2])
```

In the first line, I start with the third row of the data as the first two rows contain NAs due to the differencing. In the last line using the diffinv function, I add back the first two values of the variable of interest from the raw (level) data. Applying the same function to the y values used in the model object returns the undifferenced series. Below I attach what the predictions (red) for the variable of interest look like with the original series included in black (first in second differences and then transformed back to levels).

[image: Second difference fitted values (red) and true values (black).]

[image: Level fitted values (red) and true values (black). The original values look like a straight line which is because of the extreme scale from the transformed fitted values.]

Can you spot any problems with my approach or is there something wrong with the model? Please let me know if I can help you with any further information and I'm looking forward to your support!